# Issues with using xsl:value-of select as HTML attribute value

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am having a .jsp file where I have the code;

```
<span title="<xsl:value-of select='$fullName' />">Some text</span>
```

I have declared

```
<xsl:param name="fullName"/>
```

Now I get an error for the title attribute value used above.

If I use the same statement `<xsl:value-of select='$fullName' />`
as HTML text, it works fine

e.g. `<span><xsl:value-of select='$fullName' /></span>` works fine

My question is how do I make the xsl:value-of select work as attribute value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use a value as an attribute, you have two options. Firstly, you can use the **xsl:attribute** element

```
<span>
   <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="$fullName" /></xsl:attribute>
</span>
```

You could also make use of 'Attribute Value Templates' which are often preferred as they can make it more readable

```
<span title="{$fullName}">Some Text</span>
```

(The curly braces indicate the 'AVT' in this case).

Both methods should give you the output you desire.